# Why does trying to create a tkinter messagebox cause a 'module not callable' error?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

In this, when I run it and press the `'yes'` option on wanting to play, I get an error that says

```
line 36, in <module>
    tkinter.messagebox("Snake","Have fun!")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I have imported the `messagebox` module multiple times and it still doesn't work. can anyone offer improvements or an explanation?

Code:

```
#importing modules that I need
import tkinter                      
from tkinter import *
from msvcrt import *
#importing messagebox module separately
from tkinter import messagebox      


#the function that closes the window
def closeitall(self):               
    board.destroy()

#creating the game board
board=tkinter.Tk()                 

#setting background colour
board.configure(background="#B3C9D0")

#sets title of board window
board.title("Snake")

#sets size of board
board.geometry("700x500")               

#makes it so that the board can't be resized
board.resizable(0,0)                    

#asks question
play=messagebox.askquestion("Snake","Do you want to play snake?")   

#closes window if answer is no
if play=="no":
    closeitall(board)
#creates a messagebox 
else:
    tkinter.messagebox("Snake","Have fun!")

#closes board when escape key pressed
board.bind("<Escape>",closeitall)           

board.mainloop()
```

Comment: Format you code pleeeeease...

Comment: Why u are calling `tkinter.messagebox` ?.

Comment: Don't import something multiple times just because your first method doesn't work, it tends to make things worse. Which version of python are you running? The module is named differently in each.

Comment: I'm currently running 3.3.3, and in my last program I had to import tkinter.messagebox separately to tkinter, as it would not work without it

Comment: `tkinter.messagebox` _is_ a `tkinter` submodule which contains a number of useful functions to display different kinds of dialog boxes. Here's a [short tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_messagebox.htm) I just found that describes them (note it's written for Python 2, so the `import`s are different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like

```
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Snake","Have fun!")
```

cause messagebox is a module and not a function.

Comment: Thanks, you've made me realise I completely forgot to put the showinfo in and that screwed everything up

Answer (score 2):

You are using `messagebox` like a function.

It is actually a module, so you can't call it.